# Are text columns scriptable within Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to script the number of columns in a Docs document (not table columns, but actual text columns from Format > Columns). I believe this feature was added in the past few months, so I'm not sure if scripting for this doesn't exist yet or if it just hasn't been added to the documentation. If you know anything about this or any workarounds, let me know - thanks!

Comment: What have you already tried? An easy way to find out would be to get the body of the document and check the attributes.

Comment: There's no difference in the body attributes between having columns and not having columns, so I'm guessing there is no attribute for it. Another approach would be to call the existing Format > Columns menu item, but I don't think there is a way to call a menu item.

Comment: Your general question about a new feature that may have been added is better asked in the [Apps Script Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)